# When it comes for Android programming in Eclipse juno, I'm having a difficult in swapping EditText from one to another EditText

Tags: android, android-preferences, eclipse-juno

I'm having a problem of swapping `EditText` to another `EditText` for example in first `EditText` I input "Doraemon" then on second `EditText` I enter "Juno" so when I click the button 'SWAP' they will swap property like the "Juno" input will be at first `EditText` and in the second `EditText` is "Doraemon". I thank you in advance for those who help me.

Comment: please show us what you have tried till now! a little logic of yours that you have done so far! so we could help you in your coding style

Comment: Also, why do you use Eclipse and not Android Studio?

Comment: Ahm, because It's part of our curricular in our school. Even though, Android Studio is okay when it comes to that but the fact that it is a curricular in our school makes me mad. 